# How does a nation declare a no-fly zone?

Tags: international-relations, international

Let's assume that China declares a no-fly zone over some foreign territory.  So no other nation would be allowed to flow over the territory, because implementation of no-fly zone can only be enforced by military force (and China definitely has one of the biggest military force of the planet).

For comparison Saudi Arabia's military might is nowhere near to that of China, but it still was able to maintain naval and air blockade over Yemen.

So how does a nation implement a no-fly zone. How does it tell other countries not to deploy any flights over a certain territory otherwise the plane would be shot down. Is the message relayed via the United Nations?

Comment: The "How" aspect of this question should be asked on http://aviation.stackexchange.com/

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-fly_zone) no-fly zone can be declared by various states, UN security council etc. These are political entities and I think this question is on-topic.

Comment: I suspect the "how" here should be interpreted as "under international law, what is the process for declaring a no-fly zone?". Focusing on the legal process (which is on topic) but not the technical aviation details (which is off topic).

Comment: @indiochild To a certain extent, these are likely to be mixed up together https://www.reuters.com/article/us-un-icao-northkorea/u-n-aviation-agency-not-eyeing-no-fly-zone-around-north-korea-sources-idUSKBN1E135H

Answer (score 5):

The government just announces it, for example as a Presidential order, a speech in parliament or through the media. If the no-fly zone is targeted against a particular nation, they can also use diplomatic channels

Aircraft always need to ask for and receive permission from air traffic control before entering an airspace. Air traffic control can then simply not give that permission. The precise details of how an aircraft requests permission, and what happens if it is refused are beyond the scope of this answer.

It is then a question of whether the military of that nation can enforce the no-fly zone. Aircraft, especially non military aircraft are very vulnerable to attack. Saudi Arabia has a large and well-funded air force. It would probably not be able to defend the no-fly zone against a determined force from Nato, Russia or China. But these bloc were not willing to make the military sacrifices necessary to break the no-fly zone.

On the other hand, the Syrian government has not given America permission to fly military sorties in Syria, but he lacks the ability to prevent them.

Around the Gulf there are some peculiarities where small nations like Qatar don't control the air traffic in their airspace. When Saudi Arabia refused Qatar access to its airspace this lead to various oddities about exactly where Qatari aircraft could fly.  This is discussed further at aviation stack exchange.

Comment: Discussed where?

Comment: On the aviation stack exchange. You'll have to search for the relevant questions.